# ASP.NET Website Crashes After Exactly 50 Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm hosting an ASP.NET web API, which has been in production for several years and which has seen literally dozens of updates. All of a sudden, after only minor changes in the code, the API crashes after **exactly 50 requests**, no matter which browser or client is being used. A web server restart immediately restores API availability (application pool recycling doesn't), but the mysterious countdown begins anew...

This weird effect persists across several machines (Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2013, and Windows 7) and across different web servers (IIS 7.5, IIS 8.5, UltiDev Web Server). IDE is Visual Studio Community 2015; .NET version is 4.5.2.

I haven't added foreign API dependencies. I'm suspecting Firebird (the only external dependency) of imposing that limit of "50," but all my experimenting and googling was to no avail.

The only halfway useful log message I could extract said that the **DB connection failed due to a timeout error**. (I'm using Firebird 2.5 SuperServer x64 and Firebird .NET Provider with a *FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll* of version 3.0.2, which has served me well so far.) Still, I can connect to the DB and browse it via FlameRobin. In any case, everything works fine as soon as I go back to the previous API version.

After the crash, a previously cleared *firebird.log* contains 50 identical messages like this:

```
AB-01234-CD (Server)    Fri Nov 25 14:22:57 2016
    INET/inet_error: read errno = 10054
```

I already mentioned that the issue persists across different systems with independent local databases. DB backup/restore is useless, just like restarting the Firebird service. Only a web server restart will do.

Thanks for any ideas...

Comment: I'd imagine your not disposing of your connections and are maxing out the connection pool. without code though, this is a guess

Comment: I agree with Liam - sounds like you're not closing/disposing SqlConnections or somesuch and the connection pool is full.

Comment: Error 10054 is a (winsock) connection reset by peer. If you have a connection pool (which Firebird ado.net provider has by default), and you have 50 connections open in the pool, then the crash of the application will terminate the sockets abruptly, causing those errors to be logged by Firebird server. Firebird itself does not impose a connection limit, except Firebird SuperServer on Windows is limited to max 1024 (or 2048 in newer versions). I can only suggest you carefully scrutinize the changes between the working and non-working version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks, Liam/DrMistry/Mark,

That's what it was. The mysterious "50" is the maximum pool size in the connection string. The bug, which I was chasing for days, is one of simplest I've ever seen -- the line where the DB connection is done was **duplicated**. Like this:

```
db.Connect();
db.Connect();
```

Since only the second connection got closed, every request sent one connection into limbo, and consequently the connection pool was quickly crowded. This happens if you chance a Friday night release!

Deleting one of the two identical lines solved the issue, of course...